# Suitable run type for 4 gauge copper ground wire connecting buried grounding rods?

Tags: grounding, underground

The earth ground for our circa 1968 outdoor electrical panel in California is apparently a single maybe 8 gauge(?) solid copper wire running from a capped galvanized pipe driven into the ground (50+ years ago).

It runs from the pipe into the nearby wood in-outer-wall enclosure that holds the electrical panel, then  vertically up through the top of that wood enclosure off to parts unknown within the garage and house.  A same-sized horizontal solid copper wire is soldered to that ground wire; the other end is connected via split-bolt to a same-gauge copper wire coming out of one of the metal electrical box's knockouts along with cable (Romex?) with that copper wire seemingly bonded to the square D metal electrical box via the cable clamp, but continuing inside the box.

Recently I noticed that the stepped diamond-style clamp on the galvanized grounding pipe was corroded almost all the way through, so I will be replacing that with a new bronze clamp.

However, I will also be driving three 8 foot grounding rods nearby, connected with 4 gauge solid copper wire, and run to the electrical box's ground connection (I have not yet opened the box's front cover; it is a split-bus style panel).  My city requires that buried rod grounding systems have a protective enclosure over the top of each rod to protect it and allow for inspection. My question, however, is how to run the 4 gauge copper connecting the rods. I would like to just have it exit the bottom of each flush-buried 8-inch-deep "flowerpot" style enclosure, and run bare (no conduit) underground about 12 inches down, perhaps with a green/white ribbon buried a few inches above it to warn future excavators. Running bare would improve contact with the earth, but is it safe enough?

Photos for background info - not directly relevant to my question.

Photo of 3 "main" breakers in split bus panel - 100A(to many 20A "sub" breakers), 60A stove and 30A dryer:
[image]

Photo of 1968-era ground wires running past electrical panel - note split bolt splice on wire running into electrical panel.
[image]

Photo of solder splice of wire from electrical panel onto earth ground wire running past electrical panel and on to parts unknown in garage/house.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your existing ground wire is actually "soldered" (silver-gray colored lump of metal joining the wires, not code-compliant), or is it "exothermic welded" (typically coppery/brassy colored lump of metal jointing the wires, is code compliant)?

Comment: Cad welding is allowed but most will use irreversible compression fittings the split bolt would also be a violation, I should have mentioned that also.

Comment: It is real soldering, and it is a split bolt. I've learned enough in recent months from reading you folks' comments to realize both a not allowed now :) My information/guess is that that work was done in 1968; since I don't know where the "up and away" part of that wire goes and what it connects to, I am leaving it in place for now. My understanding is that adding a proper 4 gauge ground rod setup as well should not hurt anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The splice with solder is not allowed on the grounding system.
I the max size required by code for the grounding electrode conductor in a residential building with driven rods is #6 copper #4 is required for uffer/ or concrete encased grounding system.

I have worked in locations that the AHJ required the full 8’ to be driven below the sod level and the connection point to be accessible I used a coffee can but that was back when they were metal.

As far as the conductor I normally place the rods as close to the foundation as I can the footing keeps some rods a few inches away from the foundation I just route the wire along the foundation I have not needed any additional protection in the past this may take a few additional inches of copper. The close proximity to the foundation keeps shovels from cutting it.

Comment: Thanks. I am using 4 gauge because with the split bus the 3 "main" breakers are 100A, 60A, and 30A; I am not sure what the incoming service amperage is. Also, my understanding is that 4 gauge does not need mechanical protection under current code, so even if I run it in schedule 40 conduit instead of schedule 80 I should be OK. I like your near-the-foundation idea; we'll see where I can fit rods to avoid the shrubbery and roots by the foundation.

Comment: Residential services 100-400 amps with driven rode only need 6 awg but bigger is ok.